# Having an issue with simulator and orientation Xcode 8 swift 3 simulating iphone6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

My app works fine on my iPhone 6 device when I change the orientation.
 However on the simulator for iPhone 6, I have to repeat the following steps to get it working:

- press the home button and run Safari,
- rotate Safari to landscape, and then portrait
- press the home button again go back to my app

Now my app starts working correctly in response to landscape, portrait changes.

I'm working with `Xcode 8 beta 2` and `Swift 3.0`. I'm building for `iOS 9.3`.

This is minor but I would like to not have to do all this when checking in a simulator for orientation changes. Has anyone experienced this issue? I've tried to search for something like this but have not found it.

Comment: this sounds like a bug in the simulator... have you tried deleting your app and re-installing on the simulator? Also, quit the simulator and re-launch after deleting the app

Comment: I did more debugging on this. if I create a simple app with just a single label and then rotate the orientation in the simulator works fine the first time. When I press stop and play again on Xcode 8 beta 2 the simulator does not rotate until another app is launched and I come back to my app.  If I press the home button on the simulator before stopping my app from Xcode it works correctly the next time I press play on my app from Xcode. What is the best way to report this to Apple? can someone else confirm this as well?